# How to remove selected item from a list in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working with a d3 scatterplot and when I right click a dot a drop down menu menu appears. When I click an option (called "Remove from Library") I want to remove that selected item/dot from an array (libraryData). I am new to d3 so what makes sense to me is simply

```
libraryData.remove(d);
```

I know this isnt a function. I found something similar which was the array.splice() function. But I cant figure out how I apply that when I dont know the position of the item I want to remove in the array. 
This is where I define my function within the option of the menu:

```
{
title: 'Remove from Library',
action: function (elem, d, i) {

        d3.json("connection6.php?paperID="+d.ID, function(error, dataJson) {

            libraryData.?????();
                console.log(libraryData);   
        })
    }
```

Any help is appreciated, as you can tell I am new to d3!

Comment: have you searched anywhere online ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're kind of on the right track with `remove(d)`.

You can use this :

```
d3.select(selectedElement).remove();
```

So like the example below if you want to remove the element with ID of 'elephant' it will be like so :

```
nodes.each(function(d){
  if(d.id ==='elephant'){
    d3.select(this).remove();
  }
}
```

That is if you have the ID in the dataset. You can use anything in this check.

Or even simpler, if you know the ID is elephant it would be :

```
d3.select('#elephant').remove();
```

Or say you have an array of data and you just splice your array at the correct index.

For example :

Say you have some data and you want to remove the data with id of 'elephant';

Loop through and remove element with `id=elephant`

```
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
  if(data[i].id === 'elephant'){
    data.splice(i--,1);
  }
}
```

Notice I use `i--`. This is to update the array otherwise if you want to remove multiple elements you will get the wrong index.

Then once you splice it just update your visualization.

Comment: ah ok I understand, for the first example you showed there, where have you told d3 to remove the element from? In my case the list I want to remove the element from is libraryData.. @thisOneGuy

Comment: if you recreate your application say in, for example, JSFiddle then I can show you how to implement

Comment: Excellent answer I was able to adapt it myself and it works! thanks alot for your help really appreciate it @thisOneGuy

Comment: no problem :) would advice researching more, this wasn't too difficult to find. Sometimes its a case of what to ask I suppose, but if you don't research be prepared for some downvotes :) Glad I could help anyway